# how to get my Program name in windows-ce using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-ce

how to get my Program name in windows-ce using C# ?

if i change my program name to `ABC.exe` i want to read `ABC`

how to do it ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) to get the filename without the `.exe` like this:

```
String exe_name =      
   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
      Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName);
```

Comment: I think this will give original name, not renamed one.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this.

```
string path = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.FileName;
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```